# x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey issue with hirarchical partition key

Tags: rest, azure-cosmosdb

We are trying to create a cosmos DB document with REST API Call. We have create hirarchical partition key like /id, /date. Now when WE pass

> x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey

in header with ["value","value1"] we are getting below error.

We have also added `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey-kind` with HASH value.

> The 'kind' value 'MultiHash' specified in the partition key definition
> is invalid. Please choose 'Hash' partition type.

Comment: @MartinSmith Did you try with HTTP post Call?

Comment: Yes - it seemed to work with some adjustment of `x-ms-version` but to an unsupported version per the list here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/#supported-rest-api-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST and other tools don't have the support for Hierarchical partition keys apart from the latest version of the SDKs mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3%2Cbicep#get-started)

so it won't work with the REST API.

Comment: When I view the traffic when creating a document in such a collection in data explorer I see a post to the `docs` end point but using a later `x-ms-version` than is publicly documented - are there plans to extend the list of supported versions?

Comment: Portal uses JS SDK; I am not sure which one you're referring to!

Comment: The data explorer in the portal and viewing the traffic in Fiddler. I guess JS SDK must call that REST endpoint then - so wonder why this isn't made available for us - if the supported SDKs wind up calling it anyway presumably it works?